# How to dynamically reference imported file names in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Say I have:

```
file1 
file2
file3
```

Each of file1, file2, file3 have a dictionary called foo.

I have a different file named example_file that wants to read from file1, file2, file3.

```
from file1 import foo
from file2 import foo
from file3 import foo

# do something with file1.foo
# do something with file2.foo
# do something with file3.foo
```

Is there a way to do this through a loop?

```
for dynamic_name in something: 
   dynamic_name.foo # do something with foo
   # dynamic_name resolves to file1, file2, file3 through the loop
```

Essentially, I want to use the file names from the imports to reference items in the files themselves.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#import__) function will allow you to import a module who's name is in a variable.

To see how this works, consider this example.

```
# This...
import file1

# ...is the same as this...
file1 = __import__('file1')

# ...and this
name = 'file1'
file1 = __import__(name)
```

What if you want to import a name from the module (`from ... import ...`)? Pass the names you want to import to the `fromlist` argument.

```
# This ...
from file1 import foo

# ... is the same as
file1 = __import__('file1', fromlist=['foo'])
foo = file1.foo
```

If you have a list of module names, you can loop through them.

```
names = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
for name in names:
    module = __import__(name, fromlist=['foo'])
    foo = module.foo
    # Do something with foo
```

Or you can keep a dictionary of names and modules.

```
names = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
modules = {}
for name in names:
    modules[name] = __import__(name, fromlist=['foo'])

modules['file2'].foo  # access like this
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this in a loop to update what we reference? ie: file1 in iteration 1, file2 in iteration 2, etc

Comment: Sure. I added an example.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with

```
from file1 import foo
from file2 import foo
from file3 import foo
```

because the name foo will be reassigned every time and by the end it will only point to whatever `file3.foo` is.

Anything of the syntax `something.ofthis` is the object `something` with the attribute `ofthis`. Regardless of whether `something` is some class or a module. You can achieve the same by doing `getattr(something, 'ofthis')`. You can also use `dir(something)` to see what available attributes your object has.

```
import file1, file2, file3

for f in (file1, file2, file3):
   foo = getattr(f, 'foo')
```